# How to replace a characters in multiple positions in PHP?

Tags: php

The code is in below.I have a string.i want to replace a specific character with its fixed position.

```
$string = 'syeds nomasn shibsly';
$char = 't';
$position = [0,4,10];
foreach($position as $pos) {
  $str = substr_replace($string, $char, $pos);
}
echo $str;
```

Output will be `tyedt nomatn shibsly`
Hope you got my problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the individual characters of strings like an array:

```
foreach ($position as $pos) {
  $string[$pos] = $char;
}
```

Comment: can you please write the full code where i can get my finlal output?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code works fine with a couple of modifications.

You're not updating `$string` inside the loop, so your `$str` variable will end up with only the final position changed, since each iteration looks at the original string. You also need to pass in the length parameter to `substr_replace`, so that the correct portion of the string is replaced.

Try changing the code to:

```
foreach ($position as $pos) {
    $string = substr_replace($string, $char, $pos, 1);
}

echo $string;
```

> tyedt nomatn shibsly

See https://eval.in/968698

(You also need to fix the array syntax to use square brackets)